# How can I use jquery transform without animation?

Tags: jquery, transform

I try to change the scale of my element from 1 to 0,8.
This works well:

```
  $(this).find(".overlay").css('transform', 'scale(0.8)')
```

The only problem is, that the transformation is with an animation. How can I do this without animation?

Comment: Probably happening because of a transition. So, remove it when you add the transform: ``$(this).find(".overlay").css({ transform: "scale(0.8)",  transition: "0s" })``

Comment: @Azametzin This solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and add `$(this).find(".overlay").css({ transform: "scale(0.8)", transition: "none" })` if css is adding the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Set transition to none before using transform:

```
$el = $(this).find('.overlay');
$el.css('transition', 'none');
$el.css('transform','scale(0.8)');
```